# A Bash command to go through a list of files in a directory, find are replicates numbers 1-9, and concatenate them into a new file

Tags: bash, unix, file-management

I have a directory with a bunch of files 
Ex:

```
ExperimentA_Rep1.bed
ExperimentA_Rep2.bed
ExperimentA_Rep3.bed
ExperimentB_Rep1.bed
ExperimentD_Rep1.bed
ExperimentC_Rep1.bed
ExperimentC_Rep2.bed
.
.
.
ExperimentZ_Rep5.bed
```

I need to scan through the filenames in a directory and concatenate the files that are from the same experiment, but different replicates, into a new file.

I.e

```
cat ExperimentA_Rep1.bed ExperimentA_Rep2.bed > ExperimentA_merged.bed
```

If the Experiment only has 1 replicate, it should not do anything. But I can't hardcode this, it needs to be applicable for any dataset of experiments.

If I ran a python script that would be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this shell script:

```
for f in *Rep1.bed
do
    cat "${f%Rep1.bed}"*.bed >"$f.merged"
done
```

#### How it works

Every experiment in your example had one file whose named ended in `Rep1.bed`.  To find all files in that experiment, we can use the glob `${f%Rep1.bed}"*.bed`.  Those files are then concatenated to a single file.  This is repeated for each experiment.

The form `${f%Rep1.bed}` is an example of suffix removal.  It takes the variable `f` and removes from the end any occurrence of the pattern that follows the `%` sign.  For example, let's create a shell variable:

```
$ f=ExperimentC_Rep2.bed
$ echo "${f}"
ExperimentC_Rep2.bed
```

Now, let's remove `.bed` from the end:

```
$ echo "${f%.bed}"
ExperimentC_Rep2
```

Or, as we need here, we can remove a longer string `Rep2.bed`:

```
$ echo "${f%Rep2.bed}"
ExperimentC_
```

What is left above is the experiment name with the replicant number removed.  We can use this to select all replicant files associated with that experiment name using the glob `"${f%Rep1.bed}"*.bed`

#### As a single line

When running code interactively, it is sometimes easier to run it as a single line.  The above code, as a single line, is:

```
for f in *Rep1.bed; do cat "${f%Rep1.bed}"*.bed >"$f.merged"; done
```

#### Making a merged file only for experiments with 2 or more replicants

Some experiments have just one replicant (`*_Rep1.bed`).  Others have several: `_Rep1.bed`, `_Rep2.bed`, ....  If we want to select only files that have two or more, we can select only files for which `Rep2` exists:

```
for f in *Rep2.bed; do cat "${f%Rep2.bed}"*.bed >"$f.merged"; done
```

Comment: Can you explain why you didn't use `>>` to append to the final file or use `>` after `done`?  I haven't run this myself, but could you provide further explanation concerning this aspect?  Wouldn't your example go through each file one at a time so that "$f.merged" gets overwritten on each pass?

Comment: This definitely works, although this makes a merged file for all experiments, even ones that only have 1 replicate. Also why is the phrase "Rep1.bed" in the curly brackets. vs

Comment: @rubynorails We would do that if we wanted to create one file for all the experiments.  But, the OP wanted to _"concatenate the files that are from the same experiment, but different replicates, into a new file."_  Thus, each separate experiment gets it own file.  That is why the `>` is not after the `done` statement.

Comment: @Anonymous (1) I added code to select only those experiment for which `Rep2` exists, That way, you should only get merged files for experiments with two or more replicants.  (2) I added to the answer an explanation for _suffix removal_ which is why the phrase "Rep1.bed" was in the curly brackets.